# In a number field, $\left |R/I\right |=\left |J/IJ\right |$ for ideals $I$ and fractional ideals $J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I am trying to prove the following assertion:

> Let $K$ be a number field, $R$ its ring of algebraic integers, and let $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$. Show that $\left |R/I\right |=\left |J/IJ\right |$ for all fractional ideals $J$ (first prove it for ideals $J$, then generalize)

I could only prove it in a very particular case: $J$ an ideal (not a fractional ideal) which is relatively prime to $I$. Indeed, the inclusion of $J$ into $R$ induces an homomorphism $J\to R/I$ whose kernel is $J/I\cap J=J/IJ$ and its image is $I+J=R$.

I then tried to factor each $I$ and $J$ into prime ideals and use the fact that $\left |R/AB\right |=\left |R/A\right |\left |R/B\right |$ for every pair of nonzero ideals $A,B$. But I could not conclude. Moreover, I still have to generalize to fractional ideals, and I do not know how.

Comment: Given any fractional ideal $J$, there is $\xi\in K^*$ such that $\xi K$ is an integral ideal coprime to $I$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown 
Why? I know that if $I$ and $J$ are two nonzero ideals then there exists another ideal $B$ such that $IB$ is principal and $B$ is coprime to $J$. I do not know how to use it, nor if it is the correct way to prove it.